# Managing time sensitive pop-ups that require a user action

Tags: interaction-design, popup, interface

I have a lead follow up management tool with a feature where the leads are prioritised according to the nearest time for follow-up.

**So for example....**

lead A follow up call is scheduled for 3 hours 1 min. (181 mins)

lead B follow up call is scheduled for 3 hours. (180 mins)

lead C follow up call is scheduled for 48 hours (2880 mins)

So the list would display in time order: lead B, lead A, lead C

When the lead B follow up countdown is at 2 minutes remaining, a reminder pop up opens, asking the user to take the follow up call.

**My Questions**

1. Should I force the user (cold calling guy) with a pop up displaying the lead B information, and disable background information unless the popup is clicked on or lead called? and therefore should I minimize the pop up after 1 min?
2. If I disable the background information, what about lead A, which is just 1 min behind?
3. What should happen if the user missed the follow-up, because he was not on seat? (I have considered a section where he can check missed follow-ups)
4. Are there any good interface examples that show lead follow-ups sorted by time?

Answer (score 1):

Becareful there's a difference between a reminder popup and a regular alert popup. The difference is that a reminder popup is just to grab attention, even if you dismiss it, there should still be a sign(other than the reminder) to tell the user that something need to be done.

I imagine you have a list of items. When an item need the user's attention, it will show the reminder. When the popup is dismissed, you can still see a highlight of some sort for that item. If multiple items are due, then they will be all highlighted, there's no need to make another list just for the missed ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is absolutely imperative that user must take the follow-up call, and this is the most critical function of the application, then rather than showing a pop-up clear up his current page and ask him to take the call or user won't be allowed to do anything else. Also, give him an option to remind after 5 mins so that he can complete whatever he was doing.

Online Activity reporting tools like DART employs the same process and it has worked well for them as user is suppose to enter their daily report by 5 PM before leaving for the day.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't 'force' the user to call Lead B by a popup that disables the background unless 'the lead is called' (does the software have a way to track this btw?). This could lead to various problems (e.g. Lead A needs to be called 2 minutes after Lead B. Lead B is not called. 2 minutes pass. What happens?)
2. See answer 1.
3. Sounds like your already have the answer via the 'missed call' section. You can also send daily / weekly email reminders of missed calls, or have a module of a Dashboard tracking missed calls sorted by time / importance / etc.
4. Doesn't salesforce.com do this?